# Find the area under one arch of the cycloid $x=6(t-\sin(t))$, $y=6(1-\cos(t))$

Tags: calculus

Find the area under one arch of the cycloid $x=6(t-\sin(t))$, $y=6(1-\cos(t))$

I'm trying to figure this out using calculus. the first cycle of this cycloid will achieve a maximum height of $y=12$ and will go from $x=0$ to $x=12\pi$

So i set up the integral:

$\int_0^{12\pi}ydx=\int_0^{12\pi}6(1-\cos(t))(6-6\cos(t))dt=36\int_0^{12\pi}1+\cos^2(t)-12\cos(t)dt$

$=36\int_0^{12\pi}1+(\frac{1+\cos(2t)}{2})-12\cos(t)dt$

$=36\int_0^{12\pi}\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\cos(2t)}{2}-12\cos(t)dt$

$=36[\frac{3x}{2}+\frac{\sin(2t)}{4}-12\sin(t)]|_0^{12\pi}$

$=18(12\pi)$

Which is not correct... I'm supposed to get $108\pi$. I would appreciate some help!

Comment: Why do you integrate $t$ to $12\pi$? That's $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine, except the limits of integration for $t$. Those should be $0$ to $2\pi$. Then your next to last line should be $$36\left[\frac{3t}{2}+\frac{\sin(2t)}{4}-12\sin(t)\right]\bigg|_0^{2\pi}=36\cdot 3\pi=108\pi$$

Answer (score 1):

The integrand should be
$36(1-\cos(t))^2
= 36(1-2\cos(t)+\cos^2(t))
= 36(1-2\cos(t)+(1+\cos(2t))/2)
$

and then integrate from 0 to $\pi$.